# How to put firebase data into two tableViews?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have two tableViews in my viewController and im trying to get the information from firebase. table1 is showing the list of hotels and table 2 is showing the list of the guest emails.

I manage to populate table 1 but table 2 is just blank.

```
var Hotels : [DataSnapshot] = []
var Guests : [DataSnapshot] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView1.delegate = self
    tableView1.dataSource = self
    tableView2.delegate = self
    tableView2.dataSource = self

if (tableView.tag == 1) {
    if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
        Database.database().reference().child("Hotels").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let HotelDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let typeOfhotel = HotelDictionary["typeOfHotel"] as? Double {


                } else {
                    self.Hotels.append(snapshot)
                    self.tableView1.reloadData()
                    self.tableView2.reloadData()
                    print(snapshot)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
    {
        if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
              Database.database().reference().child("Guest").queryOrdered(byChild: "Guest Email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let guestDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if let typeOfemail = guestDictionary["Guest Email"] as? String {


                    } else {
                        self.Guest.append(snapshot)
                        self.tableView1.reloadData()
                        self.tableView2.reloadData()
                        print(snapshot)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

My CellForRowAt is

```
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
            if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

                Database.database().reference().child("Hotels").queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let snapshot = self.hotelRequests[indexPath.row]

                    if let HotelDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        if let typeOfhotel = HotelDictionary["typeOfHotel"] as? String {

                            }
                                      })
        }

    }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
        if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {

            Database.database().reference().child("Guest").queryOrdered(byChild: "Guest Email").queryEqual(toValue: email).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                let snapshot = self.Guest[indexPath.row]

                if let guestDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if let typeOfemail = guestDictionary["Guest Email"] as? String {

                            cell.textLabel?.text = typeOfemail
                            print(snapshot)
                }
            })
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

Code for numberOfRows

```
    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
    return self.Hotels.count
}
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
    {
        return self.Guest.count
    }
     else
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

I want to see two table views. tableView1 with list of hotels and tableView2 with Guest Emails

Comment: there is a typo in your code @Nick - check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the guests firebase call you are using "observeSingleEvent" instead of "observe", which maybe getting lost with two if conditions. Try using just "observe" in the firebase guest call.

**UPDATE:** there is typo in your code:

you have declared

```
 var Guests : [DataSnapshot] = []
```

but in the assignment you have just used Guest - singular.

```
self.Guest.append(snapshot)
```

Comment: is this for viewDidLoad or cellForRowAt?

Comment: i tried if for viewDidLoad and cellForRowAt, it didnt work. @srinivas

Comment: The table views are continuously being reloaded, as the function is called repeatedly when you use "observe" instead of "observeSingleEvent."

Comment: If you want the viewController to listen for changes on the backend, use "observe," if you want it to observe the state once and not again until told to do so, use "observeSingleEvent"

Comment: i did that. its like its not reading the snapshot of the Guest. @DavidChopin

Comment: and its like "var Guests" is empty

Comment: did you debug (print) to see if it entering the (tableView.tag == 2) if condition. Try to dump the snapshot before reading the snapshot values and check

Comment: there is a typo in your code @Nick - check my updated answer